# Proving that there's at least two congruent modulo p numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm trying to prove the following lemma:

Let p be an odd prime, and $r_1, r_2,...,r_{p-1}$ are the numbers $1,2,...,p-1$ in some order.

Prove that in the series $1\cdot r_1, 2\cdot r_2,..., (p-1)\cdot r_{p-1} \space$ there're at least two numbers that are congruent modulo p.

My idea was to use Wilson's theorem somehow, but I don't really have a clue how...

I'd like to receive some direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Wilson's is a good idea!

Consider the product of the series $kr_k$ for $1\le k<p$. This product is simply $$(p-1)!\cdot(r_1r_2\dots r_{p-1})=((p-1)!)^2\equiv1\pmod p.$$ So suppose that all the terms in the series were different. Then their product would have to be $-1\bmod p$.

But obviously, unless $p=2$, this is impossible. But $p$ is an odd prime, so we're done!

Comment: Thank you so much!